# SignalR SQL Scaleout

Tags: signalr

We have two SignalR instances (different SignalR hubs hosted on separate servers and those servers are load balanced). We are planning to use SignalR Scaleout with SQL Server.

We have the following concerns

1. Use Common(single) database for both the signalr hubs (seperate signalr instance), is this fine?
2. Is it possible to generate signalr related tables under custom schema name in a database, based on the signalr instances?

Comment: This question is not really about programming, I guess it should be asked on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: @blerontin -- there is a total of 5 questions on ServerFault that mention SignalR and none mention SignalR Scaleout.  There are more than 11K questions on StackOverflow that mention SignalR and 105 that mention SignalR Scaleout.  IMHO this question is quite suitable for StackOverflow -- no one on ServerFault is likely to know what he needs to know.

Answer (score 0):

1. That is the point of the backplane - a multitude of SignalR instances all using the same database. The only thing a backplane does is save messages from each instance to a central back store. Each instance will then poll the table for changes. Each instance will filter out it's own saved messages and detect the new messages from other instances, and will then send the new messages from other instances to the clients connected to it.
2. No. The `SignalR` schema name is hardcoded and is not configurable.